# How to deactivate or disable screen saver in react native application?

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to disable screen saver from the react-native application via android using the below code but it's not working. please suggest some solution.

```
@SuppressLint("InvalidWakeLockTag")
@ReactMethod
public void deActivate() {
    final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) reactContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    this.wakelock =  pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK,"DimScreen");
    this.wakelock.acquire();
}
```